# C# json.net: not able to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

This is the example json from json.net website

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

usage:

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

But when I run it I'm getting error:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type Gogch.Account. A class
>   should either have a default constructor, one constructor with
>   arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.
>   Path 'Email', line 1, position 9.

I added an empty constructor as said in another topic, but I'm still getting the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I added an empty constructor as said in another topic* Can you show us the full code for `Account`, then?

Comment: The code you've given here works fine for me. Is this *only* giving you a problem in Xamarin, or are you able to reproduce it in a quick console app?

Comment: Works in csharppad: http://csharppad.com/gist/aab77cb2581b47e05fcc3488669537f0

Comment: Is this in android?

Comment: yes, but not working in my project

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your above code...
The error is definitely somewhere else.
I ran your code using Newtonsoft.Json and it worked fine..Please go through the other portion of your source code.